# Cannot choose more than 520 files in the file upload

Tags: html, angular, file-upload

I have an input element as below (Angular 6):

```
     <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" value="Add"
          [multiple]="true" accept="image/jpeg, application/pdf" />
```

And the event:

```
  uploadFile(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

When I select up to 519 files, the element work file (the log is shown).
But if I select more than 519 files, nothing happen (the function uploadFile is not called).
I want to allow user to select up to 5000 files, is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That means, `change` event is not firing. You may be selecting an identical file already present or there may be some limit set for maximum file size or number of files. Also there is no need for value attribute in `input[type='file']`.